# Removing whitespaces from records not working correctly in SQL

Tags: sql, string, select, replace, space

I have a dataset that was cleansed thanks to another user of Stackoverflow. I have one problem though:

I have a series of telephone numbers:

```
000 6556 064666
566 2123 654566
433 4525 454252
```

I need to get rid of the white spaces to format as follows:

```
0006556064666
5662123654566
4334525454252
```

I've tried using REPLACE, but something has gone wrong because I expect the returned query to return 100,580,145 records after matching the non-white spaced rows with another table, but I am getting less than 40,000.

How can I efficiently remove these white spaces?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use **REPLACE()** function:
Try this:

```
SELECT REPLACE(column1, ' ', '') AS col1 
FROM tableA;
```

You can update the data as well:

```
UPDATE tableA 
SET column1 = REPLACE(column1, ' ', '');
```

Comment: Thanks Sahash, that worked. I was making a beginner mistake, creating a derived table then updating that instead. It gave me the numbers I was looking for.